Experiencing an error when trying to import from a diffrent directory
i am trying to import a function from another file
a/b/c.py
a/1/2.py

i wanted to import a funciton from c.py in 2.py
sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/c/py/a/b/c')
from c import function1, function2

i got this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\to\2\py\a\1\2.py", line 5, in <module>
    from c import function1, function2

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'c'


This might help, How to write a Python module/package?

The sys.path should contain the directories (and maybe ZIP files) that contain the top-level modules or packages. As c is actually a module file c.py it must not be part of a sys.path path.

This question is similar to: Relative imports for the billionth time. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
